# Refactor - separate java sources and resources

Tags: java, refactoring, resource-management

I have a large project containing both sources and resources under the same directories. Something like:

```
src  
|_ com  
  |_ package
    |_ JavaClass.java
    |_ a_resource.extension
```

I would like to separate the resources and move them all to a different root directory, retaining the same directory-package structure, like that:

```
src  
|_ com  
  |_ package
    |_ JavaClass.java
resources  
|_ com  
  |_ package
    |_ a_resource.extension
```

Is there an automatic tool for such a refactor?

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: Does it matter? I only need to run it once, so either windows / linux / mac solution would do.

Comment: ... and you presumably want it to patch all the references so it still runs?  How big is the code base (SLOC)?

Comment: I want to move them to resources dir already defined in my IDE project and build tools. My project's SLOC ~ 500K.

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: Java version 1.8

Comment: 1) What exactly do you mean by "resource"? I don't think you are talking about Java source files. How are the resource elements named, and how are they referenced from the Java code?  From each other? 2) A more general solution moves the resources up the source directory tree n=1,2,... steps (if n=depth of resource, you get your picture).  3)  If you move several resources up to depth D from different subtrees, named resources may conflict.  How do you expect that to be handled?

Comment: @Elist: I think you need to respond if you want to get any kind of detailed answer.  In the absence of further information, what you want to do (rename various artifacts, rewrite renamed files to different places) can generally be done by a program transformation system such as our http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html

Comment: @IraBaxter sorry for the lake of response. 1) Resources are any files other then java source files (**.java). The resources are referred to as `Clazz.class.getResourceAsStream("a_resource.extension")` where `Clazz.java` source file lies in the same directory as `a_resource.extension` resources do not refer each other in any way. 2, 3) moving resources up the tree isn't what I'm looking for. The resource tree has to be laid out with no modifications other then having root directory separated from the sources. This tree will allow configuring the runtime with executable and resources location.